# Imperative matching in TinkerPop / CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm want to make a query like this one

```
g.V().match(
  as('foo').hasLabel('bar'),
  as('foo').out('baz').hasId('123'),
  as('foo').out('baz').hasId('456')
)
.select('foo').by('id')
```

which is meant to select the `id`s of all nodes of type `bar`, which has `baz`-typed edges to all the specified nodes.

However, CosmosDB [only supports a subset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support) of [TinkerPop Gremlin](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/), and `match()` is among the traversal steps that are not supported.

What is a way to formulate the above query using only [supported constructs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support)?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want an "and" condition for the ids in the adjacent vertices so I would go for one of these approaches:

```
g.V().hasLabel('bar')
  and(out('baz').hasId('123'),out('baz').hasId('456'))
  .id()
```

or perhaps (note that the "2" in `is(2)` should be equivalent to the number of ids you are trying to validate):

```
g.V().hasLabel('bar')
  where(out('baz').hasId('123','456').count().is(2))
  .id()
```

I prefer this second approach I think as you only iterate `out('baz')` once to confirm the filter. You might make it a little more performant by including `limit(2)` as follows:

```
g.V().hasLabel('bar')
  where(out('baz').hasId('123','456').limit(2).count().is(2))
  .id()
```

In that way the `where()` filter will exit as early as possible depending on how quickly you find the "123" and "456" vertices. I suppose imposing the `limit()` would also protect you from situations where you have more than one edge to those vertices and you end up counting more than what you actually need for the `where()` to succeed.

Comment: Hi, is there anyway for gremlin support keyword LIKE ? I saw gremlin 2.x has filter, but 3.3 it tell us Unsupported groovy language rule: 'closure' text: '{it.name.matches(".*ark.*")

Comment: `filter()` still exists with two overloads: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate- one takes a closure and the other a `Traversal`. i'd double check your syntax a bit.

Comment: is there anyway write filter like query literal like `g.V().filter {it.get().label() == 'person'}`, I looks cosmosdb graph API do not honor filter at all.

Comment: lambdas are not supported apparently - you can read more about their plans for that here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/413

Comment: Copy that, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
 g.V().hasLabel('bar').as('a').out('baz').hasId(within('123','456')).select('a').id()
```

In a large number of cases you can avoid using the `match` step.

Cheers
Kelvin